# Career Advice. 14+ yrs expr as .Net Dev. Looking for new things

Tags: career-switch

I am a .net Dev with 14+ yrs of experience primarily in C#,ASP.NET Web forms, MCV, Winforms, WPF, SQL, WCF.

I wanted to get into integration and B2B and wanted to know what to learn to remain relevant in next decade or so.

I wanted to get in to business integration software. Learn something on that. MS Biztalk seems to be good, but it has its own issues. Software AG seems good, but I wonder if my .net experience would be valuable there.

Comment: If you’re a developer with 14+ years of experience, it should be straightforward for you to make a leap to a new platform or language.  Call yourself a “Dev” rather than a “.Net Dev”, and you’re good to go.  Your developer experience will be useful anywhere, regardless of language.

Comment: Thanks @MaxvonHippel My issues is I am doing exactly same things as I was doing in early 2010s. So I was thinking of learning some thing new. Specially in Application integration.

Comment: 1. I am unfamiliar with SE.workplace rules, but your post may be too vague / ill-defined, hence getting downvoted.  2. I will try to answer a more general form of your question.

Comment: As someone whostarted with .Net, then did a lot of database stuff, SAP ABAP, Sharepoint, and even Software AG WebMethods, I can tell you you already have everything you need to learn whatever you want. The tool isn't even half as important as the problem you use it to solve. So what do you want to do?

Answer (score 4):

**There are two questions baked into one here.**

1. "I have spent `X` years doing only skill `alpha`.  I have grown bored with `alpha`, and want to start doing something else, eg, `beta`.  How do I get a job doing `beta`, when all my experience is in `alpha`?
2. "Specifically, I am an expert in `C#`, `ASP.NET` Web forms, `MCV`, `Winforms`, `WPF`, `SQL`, and `WCF`. What is a good new field for me to move into, with this background?"

Question 1 is a question for this site (workplace.stackexchange.com).  **Question 2 probably belongs somewhere else** - possibly the Software Engineering SE, or maybe Reddit; I'm not certain.

## 1. All software engineering / software development skills are transferable.

If you have experience in `Winforms`, then `XCode` for `iOS` and `macOS` would come naturally.  If you have experience in `C#`, then `Java` would come naturally.  If you have experience in `SQL`, then all sorts of `devOps` roles would come naturally.  If you have experience *writing code*, then you are well-equiped to write code.  A good software developer can always learn to write code in a new language.  And the best way to do so is to get a job doing it.

Suppose you decide to apply to a job writing performant HPC code in `Rust`.  Obviously this would be totally outside your wheelhouse according to the description you gave of your experience.  In this case, the way to pitch yourself would be:

> I have 14 years of experience in professional enterprise-grade software development.  I want to take my experience in thoughtful software engineering and apply it to a new problem domain, specifically HPC programming in Rust.  I would begin by learning Rust on-the-job, which is probably true of any new hire from college in this position, anyway.  But unlike a new hire, I would have the benefit of 14 years of professional experience behind me, including all the leadership roles, soft skills, and project management that that experience clearly entails.

Sometimes people assume that because a job description says "applicants should have `X` experience in `beta`", they should not apply unless they have `X` experience in `beta`.  This is not true.  If you have `X` experience in `alpha`, then the person reviewing your application can judge the transferability of your skills.

## 2. You should try a job before you apply.

As a software engineer, you have the fantastic ability to try something before committing.  Suppose you are uncertain if discipline/language/whatever `gamma` would be better for you, or `zeta`.  You could:

- Start answering easy questions on Stack Overflow about `gamma` and `zeta`, and see which you enjoy more.
- Contribute to open source projects in `gamma` or `zeta`, and see which you like more.

In other disciplines, e.g., aerospace engineering, contributing like this in your free time may be more difficult.